# Ошибка UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, tkinter, время

Я только обучаюсь python. Решил проверить свои знания, и написать программу, которая при вводе time и нажатии на кнопку "Время" будет убирать весь текст и выводить время. Возникает ошибка:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\Новая папка (3)\main.py", line 6, in time
    time = time.strftime("""Год: %Y
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'time' referenced before assignment
```

вот весь код:

```
import time

def time():
    x = one.get()
    time = time.strftime("""Год: %Y
Месяц: %m
День: %d
Часов: %H
Минут: %M
Секунд: %S""")
    if x == "time":
        one.insert(0, time)

window = Tk()
window.geometry("400x400")

one = Entry(window)
one.place(x = 0, y = 0)

two = Button(window, text="Время", command=time)
two.place(x = 0, y = 25)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Многовато одинаковых имён:

```
import time
#      ^^^^

def time():
#   ^^^^
    x = one.get()
    time = time.strftime("""Год: %Y
#   ^^^^
```